# Tela de Login Java não fecha após autenticar

Tags: java, eclipse

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo um sistema inicial de login em java, com o intuito de estudar e aperfeiçoar a conexão entre o meu código e o banco de dados. O sistema consiste básicamente como um login comum, onde você informa o usuário e a senha. A ação ocorre após apertar o botão na tela, a autentificação ocorre normal, abre uma nova janela, porém eu gostaria com que ao abrir essa nova janela a tela de Login fosse fechada sem fechar a aplicação. Tentei usar o metódo Dispose(), porém sem sucesso. Se for possível me ajudarem o código é este:

package VIEW;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

import DAO.UsuarioDAO;

import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.Action;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import DTO.UsuarioDTO;

public class FrmLoginVIEW extends JFrame {

```
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField txtUsuario;
private JPasswordField txtSenha;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        
                FrmLoginVIEW window = new FrmLoginVIEW();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                
        }
    } );
}

public FrmLoginVIEW() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 229, 196);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    
    JLabel lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuário:");
    lblUsuario.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblUsuario.setBounds(10, 11, 87, 31);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsuario);
    
    txtUsuario = new JTextField();
    txtUsuario.setBounds(10, 36, 193, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtUsuario);
    txtUsuario.setColumns(10);
    
    JLabel lblSenha = new JLabel("Senha:");
    lblSenha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblSenha.setBounds(10, 61, 71, 14);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblSenha);
    
    txtSenha = new JPasswordField();
    txtSenha.setBounds(10, 83, 193, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtSenha);
    
    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Entrar");
    
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            try {
            
                String usuario, senha;
                usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
                senha = txtSenha.getText();
                
                UsuarioDTO objUser= new UsuarioDTO();
                objUser.setNome_usuario(usuario);
                objUser.setSenha_usuario(senha);
                
                UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
                
                ResultSet rsDAO = usuarioDAO.autentificacaoUsuario(objUser);
                
                if (rsDAO.next()) {
                    FrmTelaPrincipalVIEW objeto = new FrmTelaPrincipalVIEW();
                    objeto.frame.setVisible(true);
                    
                    dispose();
                    
                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario ou senha incorreto");
                }
                
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro USUARIODAO:"+ e2);
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    });
    
    btnLogin.setBounds(96, 114, 107, 31);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
}
```

}

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta reduzindo o código a um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

No código, o que está sendo instanciado e operado é a instância `frame` **dentro** da classe `FrmLoginVIEW`. O `dispose()` está sendo chamado nessa classe, e não na instância interna, por isso a tela não fecha. Para resolver, você pode ou remover esse campo da classe e operar diretamente nela:

```
public class FrmLoginVIEW extends JFrame {

private JTextField txtUsuario;
private JPasswordField txtSenha;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    
            FrmLoginVIEW window = new FrmLoginVIEW();
            window.setVisible(true);
            
        }
    } );
}

public FrmLoginVIEW() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 229, 196);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuário:");
    lblUsuario.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblUsuario.setBounds(10, 11, 87, 31);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblUsuario);

    txtUsuario = new JTextField();
    txtUsuario.setBounds(10, 36, 193, 20);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtUsuario);
    txtUsuario.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblSenha = new JLabel("Senha:");
    lblSenha.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblSenha.setBounds(10, 61, 71, 14);
    this.getContentPane().add(lblSenha);

    txtSenha = new JPasswordField();
    txtSenha.setBounds(10, 83, 193, 20);
    this.getContentPane().add(txtSenha);

    JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Entrar");

    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
            try {
        
                String usuario, senha;
                usuario = txtUsuario.getText();
                senha = txtSenha.getText();
            
                UsuarioDTO objUser= new UsuarioDTO();
                objUser.setNome_usuario(usuario);
                objUser.setSenha_usuario(senha);
            
                UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
            
                ResultSet rsDAO = usuarioDAO.autentificacaoUsuario(objUser);
            
                if (rsDAO.next()) {
                    FrmTelaPrincipalVIEW objeto = new FrmTelaPrincipalVIEW();
                    objeto.frame.setVisible(true);
                
                    dispose();
                
                }else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Usuario ou senha incorreto");
                }
            
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Erro USUARIODAO:"+ e2);
            }
                
        }
    
    });

    btnLogin.setBounds(96, 114, 107, 31);
    this.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
}
}
```

Ou então só chamar o `dispose()` no campo interno:

```
frame.dispose();
```

Comment: Boa noite, muito obrigado! Ainda estou no começo dos estudos. Deu certo dessa maneira.

Comment: Queria saber o motivo dos downvotes. O problema foi resolvido, segundo o OP. Há algum problema no código?